# I can't use "type-c" earphone as a headset(stereo) with laptop, but only in hands free mono mode(low quality)

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones, headset, headphone-jack

(bad English, I've searched on google for 4 hours, there were few things..)

I just bought an earphone from Samsung AKG, EO-IC100.
And I am using Lenovo thinkbook 16p, the laptop.
When I connected the earphone to the type-c jack(maybe upper to 3.0?)
It shows only hands-free mode in the sound setting. (image attached)
I tried playing the test video to check whether it is stereo or mono.
I couldn't hear the left sound, and the right sound was heard by all units.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZqOnRUKhb8)

How can I use this on stereo, not mono (maybe hands-free calling mode)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOZ2b.png)